# react-native-calendars, calling setState hook inside dayComponent results in infinite loop

Tags: react-native, expo

In the dayComponent within the Calendar component I am trying to update the eventDates array, by calling the setEventDates. I am reading the day specific configuration off a config file. However it seems to be going into an infinite loop and I get an error stating react-native as deduced an infinite loop and stopped it. I don't understand how the state hook variable I created is fiddling with the Calendar component.

```
const [eventDates,setEventDates] = useState([]);

<Calendar

        firstDay={0}
        onDayPress={(date) => {
          var d = new Date(date.dateString);
          setSelectedDay(d.getDay());
          setSelectedDate(date);
        }}
        onDayLongPress={(date) => {
          console.log("short press");
        }}
        dayComponent={({ date, state, onPress, onLongPress }) => {
          var dayConfig = calendarData.Days[date.dateString];
          if(dayConfig && dayConfig.event && dayConfig.event != "")
          {
            setEventDates(eventDates => [...eventDates,date.day + " - " + dayConfig.event]);            
          }
          getDayColor = () => {
            switch (state) {
              case "disabled":
                return "gray";
              case "today":
                return "red";
              default:
                return "black";
            }
          };

          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => onPress(date)}
              onLongPress={() => onLongPress(date)}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  textAlign: "center",
                  color: getDayColor(),
                }}
              >
                {date.day}
              </Text>              
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }}
      />
```

This is not the complete code. Calendar element is inside the return statement. I am using expo.

Answer (score 0):

**The issue behind the infinite loop in the props dayComponent of the Calendar component.**

Here in the code, **the statement "setEventDates" causes the infinite loop** as the setEventDates makes UI to re-render and every render will call again setEventDates.

We should return the dayComponent in the dayComponent props.

for ex.

```
<Calendar
  style={[styles.calendar, {height: 300}]}
  dayComponent={({date, state}) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: state === 'disabled' ? 'gray' : 'black'}}>{date.day}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }}
/>
```

Check out the official docs for more info.

https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars